# MongoDB findAndModify(insert only when document does not exist) and set sequence if insert

Tags: mongodb

The heading pretty much explains what I want to do

- Only insert item if document does not exist
- On insert update sequence (_id)
- Return document on insert
- If item does exist return document

Ive been reading mongo docs [Create an Auto-Increment Sequence Field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

So I've been trying to create my solution from that:

```
function getNextSequence2(x) {
 var ret = db.service.findAndModify(
      {
        query: { name: x },
        update: { $setOnInsert:{ sequence: { _id: 1 } }},
        new: true,
        upsert: true
      }
    );
   return ret.inc;
}
```

1. The Insert works and returns document ***but sequence is not updated***
2. If the document exists: ***correct*** document returns

The problem comes when i add sequence and change this:

```
 update: { $setOnInsert:{ sequence: { _id: 1 } }},
```

To this

```
  update: { $setOnInsert:{ $inc: { _id: 1 } }},
```

I get this error:

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage.
```

I've been reading all over stackoverflow, mongoDB documentation and been trying different things, I still don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

For example if i look at this query:

```
db.products.find( { qty: { $gt: 25 } } )
```

Logically mine should work?

Please help me with solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot change `_id` since it is a primary key and therefore immutable. The example ( you should have been reading ) actually suggests a "counters" collection where the `_id` is for the specific "counter" and you maintain another field like "count" with `$inc`. You want that "increment" to happen on **every** call, and not just on insert.

Comment: Ref: [Create an Auto-incrementing field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)